# Using Knockout to update the view from JSON via click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I'm attempting to update the view model every time an event fires (e.g. button click) using Knockout.  When the red button is clicked, it should read "red flower". When blue is clicked, this should change to "blue sky".

Basically, I just want clicking a button to update the view with the appropriate data.  I feel like I'm close.  What am I missing, and how would I extend this logic with a `$.getJSON`?

### Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ft8a6jbk/3

### HTML:

```
<button class="red">Red</button>
<button class="blue">Blue</button>

<div data-bind="text: name"></div>
<div data-bind="text: things()[0].item1"></div>

<script>
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

### JS:

```
var data = {
  "colors": [{
    "name": "blue",
    "things": [{
      "item1": "sky",
      "item2": "ocean",
    }, ]
  }, {
    "name": "red",
    "things": [{
      "item1": "flower",
      "item2": "sun",
    }, ]
  }, ]
};

$('.red').click(function() {
  var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.colors[0]);
});

$('.blue').click(function() {
  var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.colors[1]);
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do or fix your JsFiddle sample? Currently is not doing anything

Comment: Ah, sorry, let me reword the question. Give me a moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```
$('.red').click(function() {
  var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.colors[0]);
  ko.cleanNode(document);
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

$('.blue').click(function() {
  var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.colors[1]);
  ko.cleanNode(document);
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

It works but it's not the recommended way to use knockout.

Comment: Thank you. Your method does indeed work, but what would be the recommended way, if I might ask?  I'm interested in doing this correctly.

Comment: It seems as though you're referring to observables (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html), so that I am only binding once to the view.  How would I go about this to achieve the same goals? Perhaps I should start another question...

Comment: Everything should be in the viewModel as well as your click handlers.
For example, your view model should be something like this:
var viewModel = {
  colors: ko.observableArray([]),
  selectedColor: ko.observable(),
  setColor: function(colorName) { /* ... */ }
};

It's better not to use jQuery, but after all your code is working correctly.